# File open buffer content modification in python

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to import a tsv file into postgres db. The way I am doing is , first convert the file into csv using below code

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv(tsv_file, sep='\t', encoding='latin-1', chunksize=1000):
    chunk.to_csv(csv_file, sep=',', index=False)
```

then just use copy_expert method to insert from the newly created file as shown below:

```
     with open(csv_file, 'r', encoding = "ISO-8859-1") as file:
            with closing(conn.get_conn()) as conn:
                with closing(conn.cursor()) as cur:
                    cur.copy_expert("COPY tmp_"+table_name+" FROM STDIN WITH (HEADER TRUE, FORMAT csv)", file)
```

This works fine but how do I convert the tsv file on the fly to csv and pass this converted file object to the copy_expert? This file is large and I don't want to create the csv file from the tsv file and then insert into the table.
So far my idea is to modify the buffer of file handler received, process this buffer to convert into csv and then provide this modified file_handler to the copy expert, below code as follows:

```
with open(tsv_file, 'r', -1, encoding='latin-1') as myfile:
        temp = # space for buffer size
        for line in myfile.buffer:
            print(line)
            #process the line by converting into csv format
        myfile.buffer = temp
        # insert into the db
        cur.copy_expert("COPY tmp_"+table_name+" FROM STDIN WITH 
        (HEADER TRUE, FORMAT csv)", file)
```

This does not seem to work, print statement just prints <_io.BufferedReader name='/tmp/tsv_file.tsv'>

How do I convert the the data being read from the tsv file on the fly so I can skip creating a new csv file and then go on inserting. I did search something of iterators not sure how to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `pandas` code only translates from tab-delimited to comma-delimited, correct? In that case, just read the tab-delimited file directly and specify the delimiter in the copy command. The psygopg2 `copy_from` method accepts a `sep` (separator) argument. The SQL for the `copy_expert` version would look something like this:

```
copy tmp_table from stdin with (delimiter E'\t')
```

The `E'\t'` string is a C-style escape, documented here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-syntax-lexical.html

Otherwise, you would get `ERROR:  COPY delimiter must be a single one-byte character` if you just tried `'\t'`.

Hope that helps.